# Linear Regression - Cutting a Continuous Predictor into 2 Separate Continuous Predictors

Tags: regression, linear

I have a variable (call it V) that I want to create a linear model with.

The problem is that I want to break up this continuous variable V into 2 continuous variables (such as V1 for V<0, and V2 for V>0) - I do not want to treat V1 and V2 as factors, but I want to still keep them as continuous. What is the best way to accomplish this?

The reason I want to do this is because I can clearly see that there is a linear relationship between V and the response variable for V<0, but then the relationship changes for V>0.

Comment: you want to fit a [broken-stick function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression) with a break at a specified point? Or does the relationship "jump" at the changepoint rather than just change slope?

Comment: @Glen_b It changes slope. Does your suggestion allow for other variables to be included in the model? I just have this one variable that doesn't exhibit a nice linear trend.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure we had the conditions clear. Your question is answered on site already (more than once). I'll see if I can locate a suitable link. In the meantime you just use your original V, a new predictor V0 that is 0 for V<0 and V for V>0. You include both, along with all your other predictors. The coefficient of V is the slope before the break  (holding all other predictors constant) and the coefficient of V0 is the *change* in slope at the break, so that after the break the slope is the sum of those two coefficients.